# Monad of list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I'm trying to make this an instance of Monad in Haskell:

```
data Parser a = Done ([a], String) | Fail String
```

Now I try this code to make it an instance of Monad:

```
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Parser where
  return xs = Done ([], xs)
  Done (xs, s) >>= f = Done (concat (map f xs)), s)
```

But this obviously doesn't work, because the function `f` in the bind-function is of the type `a -> M b`. So the `(map f xs)` function yields a list of `M b`-things. It should actually make a list of `b`'s. How can I do this in Haskell?

NOTE: The actual error given by GHC 7.10.3 is:

```
SuperInterpreter.hs:71:27:
Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `a'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for return :: a -> Parser a
      at SuperInterpreter.hs:71:5
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: a (bound at SuperInterpreter.hs:71:12)
  return :: a -> Parser a (bound at SuperInterpreter.hs:71:5)
In the expression: xs
In the first argument of `Done', namely `([], xs)'

SuperInterpreter.hs:72:45:
Couldn't match type `Parser b' with `[b]'
Expected type: a -> [b]
  Actual type: a -> Parser b
Relevant bindings include
  f :: a -> Parser b (bound at SuperInterpreter.hs:72:22)
  (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
    (bound at SuperInterpreter.hs:72:5)
In the first argument of `map', namely `f'
In the first argument of `concat', namely `(map f xs)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: After you `map f xs`, check for the result list: either you have some `Fail`s, or you have none. In the former, you want to return `Fail`, I guess (?). In the latter, you can access the list of pairs inside the `Done` constructors.

Comment: It's true that I want to return Fail when one of the elements in the list is a Fail, but how exactly do I access the list of pairs inside the constructor? I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: what is the `a` here - is this the result of the parser? What is the `String`? Usually you have one return-value and one with the remaining/unparsed string and the parser is a function taking an input string and returning - for example - a tuple of some result and the remaining string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

leftaroundabout already showed you some of the problems.

Usually I expect a parser to be some kind of function that takes an input-`String`, maybe consuming some of this string and then returning an result together with the unconsumed input.

Based on this idea you can extent your code to do just this:

```
data ParserResult a
  = Done (a, String)
  | Fail String
  deriving Show

data Parser a = Parser { run :: String -> ParserResult a }

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap = liftM

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Parser where
  return a = Parser $ \ xs -> Done (a, xs)
  p >>= f = Parser $ \ xs ->
    case run p xs of
      Done (a, xs') -> run (f a) xs'
      Fail msg      -> Fail msg
```

---

#### a simple example

here is a simple parser that would accept any character:

```
parseAnyChar :: Parser Char
parseAnyChar = Parser f
  where f (c:xs) = Done (c, xs)
        f ""     = Fail "nothing to parse"
```

and this is how you would use it:

```
λ> run parseAnyChar "Hello"
Done ('H',"ello")
λ> run parseAnyChar ""
Fail "nothing to parse"
```

Comment: Ow I see now, it makes more sense to define a parser this way. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

While it's not completely uncommon to define `fmap = liftM` and so on, this is a bit backwards IMO. If you first define the more fundamental instances and base the more involved ones on them, things often come out clearer. I'll leave `<*> = ap`, but transform everything else:

```
instance Functor Parser where  -- Note that you can `derive` this automatically
  fmap f (Done vs rest) = Done (map f vs) rest
  fmap f (Fail err) = Fail err

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure xs = Done ([], xs)
  (<*>) = ap
```

Now with `fmap` already present, I can define `Monad` in the “more mathematical” way: define [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) instead of `>>=`.

```
instance Monad Parser where
  return = pure
  q >>= f = joinParser $ fmap f q
```

That means you'll work with intuitively handleable concrete values, rather than having to worry about threading a function through a parser. You can therefore see quite clearly what's going on, just write out the recursion:

```
joinParser :: Parser (Parser a) -> Parser a
  joinParser (Fail err) = Fail err
  joinParser (Done [] rest) = Done [] rest
  joinParser (Done (Fail err : _) _) = Fail err
  joinParser (Done (Done v0 rest0 : pss) rest) = ??
```

at this point you see clearly what Carsten already remarked: your `Parser` type doesn't really make sense as a parser. Both the inner and outer `Done` wrappers somehow have `rest` data; combining it would mean you combine the undone work... this is not what a parser does.

Search the web a bit, there's plenty of material on how to implement parsers in Haskell. In doubt, look how some established library does it, [e.g. parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/src/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#ParsecT).

Comment: Thank you for your clarifying answer. It's indeed clearer to really define Functor and Parser.